# sum of the squares of inverted eigenvalues of Laplacian matrix

Tags: laplacian, graph-laplacian

Consider that an unweighted graph has the Laplacian matrix $L$ which is $n \times n$.

The graph has nearest neighbors topology, so the elements on the main diagonal of $L$ are all the same.

Consider $\Lambda$ to be a diagonal matrix, consisting of the eigenvalues of $L$.

I was trying to find the explicit formula for $\text{trace}(\Lambda^{-2})$ in terms of $n$ and $m$ (the first is the number of nodes and the second is the number of neighbors for each node).

This trace is in fact sum of the squares of inverted eigenvalues of the Laplacian, i.e., $\frac{1}{\lambda_1^2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{\lambda_n^2}$.

Still I have nothing obtained for this problem that does not seem to be much difficult...

Sincerely,

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, when you say nearest neighbor topology, do you mean that each vertex has the same degree? I ask because I've heard 'nearest neighbors' in [other contexts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_graph) where it is not necessarily true that every node has the same degree.

Comment: Right. It means that each vertex has the same degree.